# Laravel 5.2 unique URL validation

Tags: php, regex, laravel-5

I am trying to validate a URL in laravel at the same time I want to make sure its unique in the database, so I am using this:

```
'url' => 'required|unique:table,url|url',
```

This is fine because it makes sure the url:
1). required
2). url is unique 
3). Here is the problem::: the formate is http://www.example.com or http://example.com or https://www.example.com or http://www.example.com/test etc.. all will pass the validation...

how can I make it if someone enters: any of these examples (http://www.example.com or http://example.com or https://www.example.com) will give an error since the "example.com" is the same ? even sub domains dev.example.com I want that to give him error since example.com is there?

Can I modify my filters and how?

Thanks

Comment: There is no direct way to achieve this, you should first get the main domain(i.e example.com) from the input. You can use explode() for that. Then use that inside the validator array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the host name for example like this:

```
if (starts_with(Request::root(), 'http://'))
{
    $domain = substr (Request::root(), 7); // $domain is now 'www.example.com'
}
```

or try using regex expression to validate:

> A single regex to parse and breakup a full URL including query
>   parameters and anchors e.g.
>
> ^((http[s]?|ftp):/)?/?([^:/\s]+)((/\w+)*/)([\w-.]+[^#?\s]+)(.*)?(#[\w-]+)?$
>
> RexEx positions:
>
> url: RegExp['$&'],
>
> protocol:RegExp.$2,
>
> host:RegExp.$3,
>
> path:RegExp.$4,
>
> file:RegExp.$6,
>
> query:RegExp.$7,
>
> hash:RegExp.$8

Comment: Thanks that's helped alot